# A question about a property of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space, and $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ and $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be two **independent** random variables. Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

I want to show that if
$$
\forall z \in \mathbb R, \Pr(f(z,Y(\omega))<0)\geq 1-\delta,
$$
then
$$
\Pr(f(X(\omega),Y(\omega)) < 0) \geq 1-\delta.
$$
How do I show this?

Comment: By using Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker That requires me to assume that $\Omega=\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$, so that I can split the integral over $\Omega$ into two components. What if my $\Omega$ is not of this sort? E.g., $\Omega = \mathbb R$ and $X(\omega) = \lfloor \omega \rfloor$ and $Y(\omega)=\omega - \lfloor \omega \rfloor$. I would have to define a new probability space, show that it is equivalent, and then do this. Am I missing something here? If not, is there a way to do this without further assumptions on $\Omega$?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then their joint distribution is given by the product measure of their individual distributions; $P\circ (X,Y)^{-1}=P\circ X^{-1}\otimes P\circ Y^{-1}$.

Comment: Hint: Denote the law of $X$ as $P^X:=P\circ X^{-1}$. By independence, $$P(f(X,Y)<0) = \int_{\Bbb R} P(f(z,Y)<0) \; P^X(dz)$$